# Google Cloud Transliteration API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-translate, google-translation-api

Google does offer Translation API, text to speech API, but is there a transliteration API that shows the pronunciation in Romanian text, like what they did in [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/)?

For example, the pronunciation of hello is `heˈlō,həˈlō`, it might differ for different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're looking for [Transliterate API](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started) but it has been deprecated long ago unfortunately. You can still use it though, but please read the [deprecation policy](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/terms) first.

Comment: Exactly! I didn't know the official term for it! Thank you